# Spark Window Function: Referencing different columns for range

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, window-functions, apache-spark-sql

I have a DataFrame with columns of `start_time` and `end_time`. I want to set windows, with each observation's window being the two rows before it by end time, restricted to data with an `end_time` before that observation's `start_time`.

Example data:

```
data = [('a', 10, 12, 5),('b', 20, 25, 10),('c', 30, 60, 15),('d', 40, 45, 20),('e', 50, 70, 25)]
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(data, ['name', 'start_time', 'end_time', 'resource'])
+----+----------+--------+--------+
|name|start_time|end_time|resource|
+----+----------+--------+--------+
|   a|        10|      12|       5|
|   b|        20|      25|      10|
|   c|        30|      60|      15|
|   d|        40|      45|      20|
|   e|        50|      70|      25|
+----+----------+--------+--------+
```

So the window for 'e' should include 'b' and 'd', but not 'c'

Without the restriction of end time < start time, I was able to use

```
from pyspark.sql import Window        
from pyspark.sql import functions as func
window = Window.orderBy("name").rowsBetween(-2, -1)
df.select('*', func.avg("resource").over(window).alias("avg")).show()
```

I looked into `rangeBetween()` but I can't figure out a way to reference the `start_time` of the current row, or that I want to restrict it by the `end_time` of the other rows. There's `Window.currentRow`, but in this example it would only reference the value for `resource`

Is this possible to do using Window? Should I be trying something else entirely?

Edit: Using Spark 2.1.1 and Python 2.7+ if it matters.

Comment: What's the `partitionBy`? Without it you'll end up with all rows in the same partition and on a single executor which will kill it with large datasets.

Comment: Yeah, my actual data is pretty large, so I have a `partitionBy` that seems to be working fine--it's groups of `name` such that each group has an a, b, c, etc. When I run the code without the restriction of only considering data with end times < current row start time, it doesn't seem to have any issues. I'm just having trouble integrating this restriction.

Answer (score 2):

you can actually use groupBy function for aggregation for different partitions  and then use the inner join between the output dataframes over the same common key. Partition by or window function takes much time in spark so better to use groupby instead if you can.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible purely using windows. From a given row, you need to be able to work in reverse sort order back through prior rows until you have two hits which satisfy your condition.

You could use a window function to create a list of all previous values encountered for each row, and then a UDF with some pure scala/python to determine the sum, accounting for your exclusions.

In scala:

```
val window = Window.partitionBy(???).orderBy("end_time").rowsBetween(Long.MinValue, -1)

val udfWithSelectionLogic = udf { values: Seq[Row] => INSERT_LOGIC_HERE_TO_CALCULATE_AGGREGATE }

val dataPlus = data.withColumn("combined", struct($"start_time", $"end_time", $"resource"))
        .withColumn("collected", collect_list($"combined") over window)
        .withColumn("result", udfWithSelectionLogic($"collected"))
```

This isn't ideal, but might be helpful.